# Change color according to data in pie chart.js

Tags: php, jquery, charts, chart.js

Here i have a Pie Graph, which is drawn with `chart.js`. And its working fine. But the problem is the, it renders same color in multiple data sets, which is looking so awkward and confusing.

**Here is a snap for that pie chart**

[image]

**Here is my AJAX code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Analytics/AdminAnalyticsCat');?>",
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var month = [];
        var customers = [];

        for (var i in data) {
            month.push("Customers in " + data[i].cat_name);
            customers.push(data[i].counter);
        }
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasDoughnut").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: month,
        datasets: [{

            data: customers,
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false
        }]

    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
    }
});
```

I tries so many times for setup their different colors, but its not working.
So Please guide me, where i am going wrong? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing anywhere in the code you posted, the mention of specifying color scheme...

Per the official documentation found @ http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/, you need to do the following --- tweak it as needed

```
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
```

put the above before `options: {`

Comment: my data and labels are not fixed.Its dynamic and comes from AJAX response. now how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function which generates random colors for each bars:

```
 var randomColorGenerator = function () {
           return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
        };

var barChartData = {
               labels: ["Your label sets"],
               datasets: [
                   {
                       label: "My First dataset",
                       fillColor: randomColorGenerator(),
                       strokeColor: randomColorGenerator(),
                       highlightFill: randomColorGenerator(),
                       highlightStroke: randomColorGenerator(),
                       data: [Your datasets]
                   }
               ]
           };
```